# CakePHP find record that matches in two tables

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two tables: Users and Profiles. A user may have a profile and a profile must have a user!

The tables are:

**Users:**
id
username
email
password

**Profiles:**
firstname
lastname
gender
dob
user_id

So as you can see the profiles table links back to the users via the user_id key

How do I view a profile based on the username of that user?

As it needs to pull information from both tables... so far I have:

```
public function view ( $username )
{
    $profile = $this->Profile->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array('User.username' => $username)
            ));

    if (empty($profile))
    {
        $this->cakeError('error404');
    }

    $this->set(compact('profile'));
}
```

and this is the route for it:

```
Router::connect('/people/:userName',array('controller'=>'profiles','action'=>'view'),
    array(
        'userName'=>'[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+',
        'pass'=>array('userName')
    )
);
```

Also here are the Models:

User:

```
class User extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'User';
}
```

**I have not specified the user hasOne profile, as the user may not have a profile. e.g admin account**

Profile:

```
class Profile extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Profile';

    var $belongsTo = 'User';
}
```

and here is my view:

`<h1><?php echo $profile['Profile']['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $profile['Profile']['lastname']; ?></h1>`

But need some steer to get it correct. According to the CakePHP 2.0 book I can do something like: `$this->User-Profile->` but I don't fully understand it or how I could use it here???

For example would this be correct:

`$profile = $this->Profile->User->find('first', array(
                    'conditions' => array('User.username' => $username)
                ));`

Thanks

Comment: set up the `$hasOne` relationship. It doesn't mean you are *required* to have a profile, but that you can only have *one* profile. You can then access the data through the associations (`$this->User->Profile`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your routes, you are going to use a 'User' model from  ProfilesController. For this to work, you should add after the `class ProfilesController extends Controller`  the following line :

`public $uses = array('User','Profile');`

Then you get directly the User model like this :

`$this->User->...`

I may be wrong, but I don't think you could possibly do `$this->Profile->User`

**[EDIT :]**

after discussing this, it appears the User Model should really have `$hasOne='Profile';`

Because it does not enforce a profile, but just get it from database if it ever exists.

Comment: Okay tried that but in my view I get the error: `Undefined index: Profile [APP/View/Profiles/view.ctp, line 1]` Posted my view code in OP

Comment: @Cameron it is okay, because indexes have changed. Just `debug($data)` and fix your view accordingly

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. What is the problem with the index?

Comment: @Cameron no, Cakephp 2.0 has not changed this. Are you trying to migrate from cakephp1.3, because you could benefit from their [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html?highlight=migrating)

Comment: ok, paste the debug($data) here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6265/about-so-8680577

Comment: Nope I'm writing in 2.0. I was referring to `$this->Profile->User` might be new as it works the same as passing two models to the controller. But what's the issue with the index?